# Unable to test default values via mount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

New to react testing and having issues when trying to render props based on default values.

Tests passes fine if I pass in value.

Unable to understand why. Could I please get some assistance on this. Thanks.

This is the error:

```
Invariant Violation: <Media targetWindow> does not support `matchMedia`.
```

Some default values for testing inside test file.

```
const listOfItems = [
    [
        {
            "header": ""
        }
    ]
];

const defaultProps = {
    data: {
        contentData: {
            main_group: {
                items: listOfItems,
                main_header: ''
            },
        },
    },
};
```

This is test portion within same file

```
const render = props => mount(<MyComponent {...defaultProps} {...props} />); // mount is from 'enzyme'

// This test fails 
it('should test something', () => {
    // issue is with render().props()
    expect(render().props().data).toMatchSnapshot();
});

// This test passes 
it('should test another', () => {
    const tempRender = render(
        {
        ...defaultProps,
        data: {
            contentData: {
                main_group: {
                    items: listOfItems
                },
            },
        },
        }
    );
    expect(tempRender).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code of the component you are testing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by mocking `window.matchMedia` API in the Jest config, e.g.:

```
window.matchMedia = () => ({ 
  addListener: () => {}, 
  removeListener: () => {} 
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media/issues/86#issuecomment-378295443